# Simple PHP Login with .txt not working

Tags: php, web

This is `login.php`. A user enters a username and password on the previous page. Database stores information in the format "user|pass". Using the explode function to separate user and pass with "|".

$details[0] finds a match on the same line. But not for $details[1] even though the inputted data is correct with the actual .txt file.

```
$user = $_POST['user'];
$pass = $_POST['pass'];  

$db = file("database.txt");

$valid = false;
foreach ($db as $person) {
  $details = explode('|', $person);
  if ($details[0] == $user && $details[1] == $pass) {
      // Found a math to the database.
      $valid = true;
      break;
  }
}
```

Why is this the case?

Thanks

Comment: try `error_log(print_r($details,TRUE))` and look in the log file to see what's actually in your `$details` array.  You will most likely find that your "database" records aren't in the format you expect them to be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***You need to use [file()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php) standered parameters which are:-***

```
FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES
```

So code need to be:-

```
$user = $_POST['user'];
$pass = $_POST['pass'];  

$db = file("database.txt", FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);

$valid = false;
foreach ($db as $person) {
  $details = explode('|', $person);
  if (trim($details[0]) == $user && trim($details[1]) == $pass) {
      $valid = true;
      break;
  }
}
```

***Note:-*** Try to use database to manage user records along with hashed password for security purpose.Thanks

Comment: Using the flags when reading from the file is the correct solution. +1

Comment: @fubar  thanks. Yes that's the most efficient way (As it is provided by-default).

Comment: Indeed. I hadn't considered looking for flags :)

Comment: @TravisS.  WELCOME :):)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is because the end of every line has a `\n` character, which is preventing the password from matching.

If you trim the newline character, it will match.

```
$details = explode('|', trim($person, "\n"));
```

And of course you already know storing passwords in plain text is really bad.

Comment: You just, display my thought

Answer (score 1):

Try **`trim($details[1]) == $pass`** to remove the newline from the end of the password read from the text file.

Better yet, use a database table so you don't have extra characters attached to your data.

...and, as @fubar has pointed out, storing passwords as plain text is a major security hole.